# SQL Server - highlight sequence of rows with specific conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

From my query I get:

```
----------
| Val  |  Avg |
----------
|  1   |   7  |
----------
|  5   |   7  |
----------
|  2   |   7  |
----------
|  5   |   7  |
----------
|  6   |   7  |
----------
|  5   |   7  |
```

Assume the above is in some table "t". I want to check if there are three or more rows where the value is less then the corresponding average. If there are three or more points that satisfy that condition then they should be highlighted in a result like this:

```
----------
|  Val |  Avg | BelowAvg |
----------
|  8   |   7  |     0    |
----------
|  7   |   7  |     0    |
----------
|  9   |   7  |     0    |
----------
|  5   |   7  |     1    |
----------
|  6   |   7  |     1    |
----------
|  5   |   7  |     1    |
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sequence of rows as ordered by what? Version of SQL Server?

Comment: The rows don't need to be ordered. It's just a pattern that is occurring where the value is less than the average in 3 or more rows. Those rows should have a 1 in the BelowAvg column. It's Sql Server 2012

Comment: @user2755428 Then there is an order. As you say yourself "average in 3 or more rows", what rows are those?, the previous or latter 3?, according to what?

Comment: @user2755428 So you don't care if there are three in a row? (because if you do an ordering is required). You need to explain it better anyway. Where does the `Avg` come from? Why is it not the same in all rows?

Comment: Can you show us some sort of query?

Comment: @Dukeling, I think you are misunderstanding. Yes 5>3, but the row above, 1<3, and 2<3. So, a sequence is not being formed of values that are less then their average. If look at the bottom three rows they form a sequence of values that are less then their average. 5<7,6<7,5<7, three in a row!

Comment: @MartinSmith. It's really not relevant where Avg comes from. Just from this table is it not possible to detect numerous consecutive rows where the value is less then it's corresponding avg?

Comment: but we need to know how you are grouping your data to get this average ...cause what will happen if you have 2 sets of data that giving the same average...do you see the problem?

Comment: I think have confused myself along with everyone else. Let's start simple and say that the entire Avg column is 7! Does that help?

Comment: but now BelowAvg will be 1 everywhere...

Comment: my solution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/220501/2

Comment: You make it more complicated :) ...as you put it now...it's unsolvable...how we can determine which `VAL` to considere for a specific `AVG`? Take a look at the second part my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with your previous data. A problem will arise when you will have the same average for another set of `VAL`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8271c/5)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ([Val] int, [Avg] int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    ([Val], [Avg])
VALUES
    (1, 3),
    (5, 3),
    (2, 3),
    (5, 7),
    (6, 7),
    (5, 7)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       CASE WHEN t2.cnt >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as BelowAvg 
FROM t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT avg, count(*) as cnt
            FROM t
            WHERE val < avg
            GROUP BY avg) t2 ON t.avg = t2.avg
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8271c/5/0)**:

```
| VAL | AVG | BELOWAVG |
|-----|-----|----------|
|   1 |   3 |        0 |
|   5 |   3 |        0 |
|   2 |   3 |        0 |
|   5 |   7 |        1 |
|   6 |   7 |        1 |
|   5 |   7 |        1 |
```

**EDIT:** Assuming that this is related to a question, you can have something like this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ab0e/3)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ([QuestionID] int, [Val] int, [Avg] int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    ([QuestionID], [Val], [Avg])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 3),
    (1, 5, 3),
    (1, 2, 3),
    (2, 5, 7),
    (2, 6, 7),
    (2, 5, 7)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       CASE WHEN t2.cnt >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as BelowAvg 
FROM t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT QuestionID, count(*) as cnt
            FROM t
            WHERE val < avg
            GROUP BY QuestionID) t2 ON t.QuestionID = t2.QuestionID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ab0e/3/0)**:

```
| QUESTIONID | VAL | AVG | BELOWAVG |
|------------|-----|-----|----------|
|          1 |   1 |   3 |        0 |
|          1 |   5 |   3 |        0 |
|          1 |   2 |   3 |        0 |
|          2 |   5 |   7 |        1 |
|          2 |   6 |   7 |        1 |
|          2 |   5 |   7 |        1 |
```

Comment: For others looking at this solution, @FabienTheSolution 's answer works well!